# How to send POST in liferay portlet?

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portlet

Hi im begin lern liferay and have one problem. I cant send POST in portlet from jsp.

In jsp i have :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<portlet:defineObjects />

<div>
  <form action="HelloWorld" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div id="up">
    <input id="fileUpload1" type="button" name="filename" value="Привет">
   </div>
   </form>
 </div>
```

in portlet:

```
public class HelloWorld extends GenericPortlet {
protected void doGet(ActionRequest request,
     ActionResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
     { 
 // reading the user input 
 //String color= request.getParameter("color");
 HttpServletResponse servletResponse = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(response);
 PrintWriter out = servletResponse.getWriter(); 
    out.println("<HTML>");
    out.println("<HEAD <TITLE> Upload4 </TITLE> </HEAD>");
    out.println("<BODY>");
    out.println("<FORM action = \"HelloWorld\" method = \"post\" enctype = \"multipart/form-data\">");
    out.println("<div id='up'>");
    out.println("Hello World!!");
    out.println("<input id='fileUpload1' type='button' name='filename' value='Привет'>");
    out.println("</div>");
    out.println("</FORM>");
    out.println("</BODY>");
    out.println("</HTML>");
 } 
     }
```

Where i can mistake? I gonna write something in portlet's XML files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is wrong on so many levels - sorry - that I don't know where to start:

- You should post to `<portlet:actionURL />`, not to "`HelloWorld`"
- You should implement `processAction` instead of `doGet` (which sounds rather like a servlet)
- You must not get access to the original `HttpServletRequest` in your action handler in order to write content
- In action handling you just handle the action, during the render phase you render the HTML you need
- the HTML you generate does not contain `<html>`, `<head>`, but just some part that the portal will embed on a page
- and I feel like I missed a few more things...

I recommend to start with some tutorial - like the [Liferay in Action](http://www.manning.com/sezov/) book - to get the basic concepts.

Comment: Tnx for book. I do all corections what you write but, servlet dont generate new page.

Comment: As Olaf said, there are quite a few things to unlearn to learn, please go through some documentation. Liferay's official documentation has everything to get started with what you are doing. http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/portlet-developme-3

Answer (score 2):

Action attribute in form tag should be `<portlet:actionURL />`

```
<form action="<portlet:actionURL />" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Also in portlet java file implement `processAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)` method for POST.

Comment: <portlet:actionURL = "/HelloWorld"></portlet:actionURL> <form action=var method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> Like this?

Comment: I change public void processAction(ActionRequest request,
     ActionResponse response) throws IOException
     {  But nothing to change